# In bootstrap, how make the thumbnails fluid resize well

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I'm using bootstrap 2.0 to make a fluid layout. However, I find it break bad when the browser is resize or when I see it from a iPhone:

[image: Thumbnanil break bas]

This is my markup:

```
      <div id="features" class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
          <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" width="128" height="128" alt="Orders" />
                <h3>Pedidos</h3>
                <p>Genera ordenes de pedidos para su facturacion posterior</p>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" width="128" height="128" alt="Invoices" />
                <h3>Facturas</h3>
                <p>Factura las ventas realizadas</p>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" width="128" height="128" alt="Customers" />
                <h3>Clientes</h3>
                <p>Ingrese & actuelize los datos de los clientes</p>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" width="128" height="128" alt="Products & Stock" />
                <h3>Productos</h3>
                <p>Ingrese & actuelize los datos de los productos y su inventario</p>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" width="128" height="128" alt="Sincronization with ERP" />
                <h3>Impresion</h3>
                <p>Genera impresion de tiquets en papel con la impresora P25</p>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" width="128" height="128" alt="Sincronization with ERP" />
                <h3>Sincronizacion</h3>
                <p>Sincroniza los datos con ERPs seleccionados</p>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/span-->   
      </div><!--/row-->
```

(The same markup with zero CSS aplied break bad too)

I have tried by CSS to put a width/height but that break the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap now have responsive support, and the 3.0 Branch [will have it by default](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/3.0.0-wip).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using images that are exactly the same size and distributed evenly, it's very difficult to resolve your challenge with pure css, despite how magical boostrap is. You might try using `.row` instead of `.row-fluid` to see if the fluid styles are causing bad breaks, but beyond that you may need to consider using javascript if you want something "bulletproof".

maybe something like: [masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html)